# Visual studio code end of line setting (file with inconsistent line endings)

Tags: visual-studio-code, eol

Is it possible to keep original end of lines in the file?
(I use visual studio code to edit files on a linux server through SAMBA)

There is a button at right bottom to choose either LF or CRLF,
but it replace all the end of lines in the file.

example:

```
 line1 \r\n
 line2 \r\n
 line3 \n
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it is not possible in VSCode to preserve the original line endings when they are not the same throughout a file.  Internally, for each file, VSCode only stores a single `_eol` value, and when multi-line text is requested, inserts it between every line on the fly.

See, for example, method `getText()` in [mirrorTextModel.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/common/model/mirrorTextModel.ts#L51).  `MirrorTextModel` is a base class of [`ExtHostDocumentData`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostDocumentData.ts), which implements the [`TextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument) entity exposed in the API.