# VSCode not defaulting to \n end of line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Generally me and my developers prefer UNIX line endings. I have updated the setting in VSCode for end of line settings to the following...

```
"files.eol": "\n"
```

This seems to work when creating new files, however any pre-existing file from our source code is defaulted to CRLF. Is there any way that I can set our end of lines to \n across all files, even pre-existing files from our repo's source code?

Comment: That would be a serious pain for code reviews and change tracking, if the IDE were to strip every file you open of its line endings and change them to something else.

I've had it happen accidentally in one project (some git settings can cause it) and it caused no amount of headaches having every single line in every single file reported as changed.

Answer (score 2):

When VSCode opens a file, if the file has at least one line terminator in it, its [per-file EOL value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57732329/2659307) will be [set according to whatever is the most common line terminator](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.37.1/src/vs/editor/common/model/pieceTreeTextBuffer/pieceTreeTextBufferBuilder.ts#L25-L38) in the file, regardless of `files.eol`.  That means that if files are opening as CRLF, then those files are *already* CRLF on disk.

My guess is your [SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) is checking them out with CRLF endings and you probably can adjust its configuration so it checks them out as LF instead.